# Call MVC5 void method from javascript code in cshtml view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

How to call controller`s void method from javascript MVC5

```
public void BetResult(int winvalue)
{
    _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId()).Balance += winvalue;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Spending hours and tried to do this with ajax but still can`t find the correct solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. I'd recommend adding [a little more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to your question to help you out.  Could you also add a little more code? Is this method on a Controller? API Controller? What about a sample of the js you tried?

Comment: Show your javascript. Lots of examples out there like [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-Example.aspx). Also, don't make the controller action `void` - make it a JsonResult and return a success indicator. The code above will throw an exception if the user is not found, so check for that.

Comment: Thanks Steve, you helped a lot

Comment: I would turn your C# method into an API, and have javascript use AJAX to hit the route